# what are the penances for a brahmin who has broken his vow of celibacy according to parasara smriti

Tags: brahmacharya, prayaschitta

According to Kali Yuga what are the penances that a student can do for this rather than donating one eyed donkey? please do not include references from Manu Smriti.